# Change the background color of rows as a group in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable and want to have a clear distinction between the rows through color coding as shown in image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUIG7.png)

I know we need to use cell renderer but I am not sure how to compare the value of cells.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003600/jtable-not-coloring-row-correctly/49004011#49004011) - but it's a bit hard to know what to suggest based on the description

Comment: Please post your `TableModel`

Comment: So it seems like you want the "odd" valued groups one color and the "even" valued groups another color. I would override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29702874/131872 for an example and more information to get you started.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.